# Why does normal incidence eliminate the photocarrier effect radiation in this experiment?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, semiconductor-physics

[Here's a paper](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/apl/64/11/10.1063/1.111922) in which they use GaAs crystals at a few orientations to produce THz radiation, by means of Optical Rectification (OR). That's actually not what this question is about, though.

They warn that, in doing this experiment, they needed to make sure they weren't measuring radiation contributed by the "photocarrier effect", which I hadn't really heard of to begin with -- if you Google that term, it doesn't really return anything coherent and common.

But I think I figured out what it is. From [this book:](http://www.springer.com/978-1-4419-0977-0)

[image]

So it basically seems like the incoming wave creates an electron-hole pair, and then this electron hole pair oscillates because of the charge imbalance and E field, creating dipole radiation (apparently in the THz range). This I'm okay with, I guess.

But back to the paper, they say:

> The THz radiation contributed by the photocarrier effect can be
>   eliminated with the use of normal incidence, since there is no
>   radiation along the dipole axis in the direction of the surface field.
>   In general, at normal incidence the forward THz radiation from
>   zinc-blende crystals is purely due to optical rectification.

And this is very confusing. Starting from the beginning, if you have your incidence light at normal, then your E field from that light is entirely parallel to the surface.

Now I originally thought that this incident E field was what's driving the dipoles at the surface, but that doesn't make any sense, because then the dipole would also be pointed in the same direction as the incident E field, and [dipoles have *maximum* radiation at 90 degrees from their axis](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Dipole.gif), so that really wouldn't make sense here (the radiation from the dipole would be also normal to the surface).

So, according to the excerpt from that book I posted above, it seems like the incident light *creates* the electron hole pair, but then what actually makes it oscillate is the built-in E field, $E_S$; if you notice, the incident field is nowhere in that equation. Furthermore, they then say that "...and the normal of the dipole oscillation, which is perpendicular to the surface...". It's pretty confusing because it's not clear when they say 'which' whether they're referring to the *normal* of the dipole oscillation or the dipole oscillation itself, but I think it's the latter, based on the diagram: the built in field is only in the direction perpendicular to the surface.

So if this is the case, the dipoles are oscillating normal to the surface, and you shouldn't get any radiation in that direction.

So, my question is then, why does the angle of the incident light matter at all? It seems like the incident light just creates the electron-hole pair, but from there the oscillation direction is fixed. In fact, if we say that the incident E field *does* affect their oscillation direction, that makes things worse for "eliminating" this source of radiation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

What you said is right. The incident field creates the electron-hole pair, then they oscillate normal to the surface. Since the motion is normal to the surface, it radiates in every direction *except* normal to the surface. (Dipole radiation pattern.) So if you want to avoid that effect, you want the *outgoing* light you measure to be normal to the surface.

If optical rectification is to produce light going normal to the surface, the *incoming* light should be normal to the surface too. That's because of ... I think ... phase matching considerations (?)